# Continuous Deployment - Modify backend url in the frontend before deployment

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

My current situation:
I have a jenkins pipeline to dockerize my node/express backend and build+dockerize my react frontend after every commit to github. This works so far. I am using docker and jenkins on ubuntu 18.

Problem:
My frontend (of course) can't connect to the backend when on the live server (because the route to the backend is `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. My first idea was to use environment variables but this is not working since react can't read env variables after built (because it's pure html/css/js). What are common solutions to this problem? I don't want to change the backend to the actual domain every time before I push to the repository and change it back to 127.0.0.1 to work on it again.

Comment: Can you pass the backend endpoint as an argument of build tool for react? If so you can create a jenkins job parameter to let user input/choose endpoint value

Comment: Are you using create-react-app?

Comment: @MateuszKrzyżanowski yes I used create-react-app to initialize the project.

Comment: @yong can you elaborate or give me a link? I can not really understand.

Answer (score 0):

I researched some more and environment variables CAN be replaced by their value in build time (which is what I want) when you don't use an npm package like dotenv, but rather define variables that start with REACT_APP_.

[More Information](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

"The environment variables are embedded during the build time" - should have read that before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [env files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/#what-other-env-files-can-be-used%20to) to define different variables based on the environment